# Objects move together

Tags: objects

[image]

I'm trying to move one of the objects, but instead of just one moving, they all move.

Comment: You turned on proportional editing. Disable it, and it should work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've enabled the Proportional Editing option (blue sphere icon on the horizontal bottom menu bar)

Comment: I just realized